# Do browsers (chrome/firefox/safari) cull non-visible svg shapes?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, quadtree, culling

We currently have a screen reaching about 10000 shapes. We are allowing users to pan and zoom to explore.  I thought of a couple optimizations to keep using svg in the mid-term:

1. culling shapes not on screen (only writing objects in our viewport to the DOM)
2. reducing edges when zoomed out

These 2 tactics go hand in hand; however, I was wondering if shapes not already on screen are already culled and not "drawn" by most browser vendors. If not, is it presumably better maintain a quad tree of objects in the scene and render the current set of trees that intersect with our viewport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Firefox since [version 17](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=776054) has culled shapes that can't be seen. The code creates what is called a [display list](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko%3aDisplayListBasedInvalidation) of things that it intends to draw. I imagine sure Chrome and IE use some similar mechanism so you'd only make things slower if you try to handle it yourself.